# Are different LaTex editors compatible with each other?

Tags: templates, latex, compatibility, overleaf

I am editing a .tex document in Overleaf. My question is, is the .tex file that I create in the Overleaf project can be opened, used, or edited by any other LaTex editors, or are there editors that use commands unique for the editor program?

Comment: The editor does not matter,  in general a tex file should work everywhere. What might matter is the version of  your tex distribution. Overleaf uses TexLive 2022. If you use an older or newer version some things might behave differently.

Comment: The compiler may also matter. Overleaf has four different options and what works in one compiler may or may not work the same in another—but you can test this by changing the selection in Overleaf.